# How to use tesseract_ocr in PHP?

Tags: php, tesseract.js

I find a problem to use tesseract_ocr in php, I follow this tutorial https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php.

I install tesseract_ocr use composer :

```
$ composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr
```

this is my folder structure in localhost :

[image]

this is mycode :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
echo (new TesseractOCR('images/8055.PNG'))
    ->whitelist(range('A', 'Z'))
    ->run();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my php version :

[image]

and in the browser I get this error :

> `Fatal error: Uncaught thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractNotFoundException: Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. Make sure you have Tesseract OCR installed on your system: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract The current $PATH is C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Users\frank\AppD in C:\xampp\htdocs\ocr\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php on line 48`

please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to install the tesseract program in your computer.

Comment: From your own link: **‼️ This library depends on Tesseract OCR, version 3.02 or later.** and

Comment: yah, actually I have installed tesseract in my computer, but not working

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yah, I have installed this library ver5.0.0 from this link https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki, but my code above still error

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library but if you haven't added the program to system PATH I presume you need to set the full path somewhere in your code. PHP needs a clue of where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Tesseract OCR on your pc from here:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Then your code should be(just in case you are on windows, C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe is the path of Tesseract engine):

```
echo (new TesseractOCR($img_url))
        ->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')
        ->whitelist(range('A', 'Z'))
        ->lang('eng')
        ->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the tesseract folder is in your path.

If you're unsure what I'm saying, click on the start button and type "edit the system environment variables".  Click Environment Variables, under "System variables" click on the line that has "Path" on the far left, and click edit.  Click "New" and put in the path to your executable, depending on if you're using the 64 bit or 32 bit version.  In my case it was "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR".

You can test this now by opening a new command prompt (if you had an old one open, it won't have the new path variable), and type tesseract and hit enter.  You should see:

```html
Usage:
  tesseract --help | --help-extra | --version
  tesseract --list-langs
  tesseract imagename outputbase [options...] [configfile...]

OCR options:
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
NOTE: These options must occur before any configfile.

Single options:
  --help                Show this help message.
  --help-extra          Show extra help for advanced users.
  --version             Show version information.
  --list-langs          List available languages for tesseract engine.
```

If you do, then it's installed and globally working on your machine now and should work with PHP.   If you want to get it working without composer, look up my other answer about that on here.